# How to clear the validation message after value is entered

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, razor, razor-pages

I have the following code in the cshtml page

```
 <div class="col-md-3">
 @Html.EditorFor(x => Model.SubscriptionId, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control " }})
 @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => Model.SubscriptionId, "Subscription Id is required")
 </div>
```

The validation message is not cleared even after entering a valid value in the field. How should I fix this?

Comment: As per the default validation by ValidationMessageFor, if the focus from the textbox is lost then it will clear the validation message. To fix this, you can use client side validation instead of server sided -  you can use the javascript or jquery and call the validation methods and use onkeyup event in it. So while typing unless the given value is right it will show validation error, once it is correct it will clear the error message.

Comment: Razor is not a good option till date for operation over html elements.